# Applying ks.test on a huge data set

Tags: r

I am looking to make ks.test in order to compare between two distributions. Therefore here is the way how I proceeded:

1. I loaded `vec1` from a file, `length(vec1) = 720642` : which is a too big data set.
2. I applied `fitdistr(vec1,"lognormal")` -> Here I get the most suited `meanlog=1.69` and `sdlog=1.02` that best fits the distribution of `vec1`
3. When I simply apply :

   `ks.test(vec1, "plnorm", 1.69, 1.02)`

   I get: `D = 0.1429`, `p-value < 2.2e-16`
    alternative hypothesis: two-sided

So the test fails and it is like I am not dealing with a lognormal distribution ....

Has anyone the solution for that? Is it because I've loaded from the file a huge data set?

Comment: If the sample size is big, the ks test will find very small deviations from the assumed distribution. Furthermore, `?ks.test` states "If a single-sample test is used, the parameters specified in ... must be pre-specified and not estimated from the data. There is some more refined distribution theory for the KS test with estimated parameters (see Durbin, 1973), but that is not implemented in ks.test."

Comment: @Roland this means that there is no way that ks.test will give an accurate result with a big number of samples ?
You said: _the parameters specified in ... must be pre-specified and not estimated from the data_. I actually tried ks.test(vec1, vec2) such that vec2 follows the lognormal distribution having for parameters the cited meanlog and sdlog, and its size is the same as vec1, but always the same result ...
Any help ? thanks.

Comment: I suggest to turn this in a statistical question like so: 'I want to test if a large sample is from a log-normal distribution. `?ks.test` says ... What is the best way to procede.' (Put a bit more effort into formulating your questions and do some research first.) and post it on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For big data set, you will always reject H0 (with any specified reference distribution) due to the large power for large data set.